# Looking for a Automated Cloud solution that allows access to servers behind VPN

Tags: automated-testing, aws

I am looking for an Automated Cloud testing solution that would allow my app an access to my company's servers that are situated behind a VPN.
I am using OpenVPN to allow the devices to expose them to the servers, I'd like to be able to automate this process.
Did anybody manage to overcome this issue?
Thanks a lot, Pavel

Comment: You can have a look at Browserstack which supports this kind of testing with the localtesting. In their site they have given samples. https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing

Comment: It appears they don't support testing with Espresso/Calabash which I use :/ Thanks for the help, Bhavani

Comment: I see they do support Calabash but with Ruby, not Java :/

Comment: They are supporting Java also. Please check this link: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/java

Comment: Hmm, these look like WebDriver/Appium tests. We are using Espresso for Android..

Comment: I think [SRF might help](https://software.microfocus.com/ru-ru/products/functional-testing-as-a-service/overview)